# MVC - GET & POST actions with the same name and parameters in the same controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an MVC4 project, and I have two actions in the same controller with the same name and parameters:

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateBananaViewModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
        model = new CreateBananaViewModel();

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateBananaViewModel model)
{
    // Model Save Code...

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The reason I want to pass an existing model into my Create method is to clone and then modify an existing model.

Obviously the compiler doesnt like this, so I've changed one method to look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateBananaViewModel model, int? uselessInt)
{
    // Model Save Code...

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Is this perfectly acceptable? Or is there a nicer way of getting around this problem?

EDIT / SOLUTION:

Looks like I completely over complicated the situation. Here's my solution

```
public ActionResult Duplicate(Guid id)
{
    var banana = GetBananaViewModel(id);

    return View("Create", model);
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new CreateBananaViewModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You can also use the ActionName attribute to have the same signature for the Create and Update method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really need a `model` param at GET `Create` action? You can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new CreateBananaViewModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

or, if you wish to receive some query data to the action (`www.mysite.com/banana/create?bananaType=yellow`)

```
public ActionResult Create(string bananaType, string anotherQueryParam)
{
    var model = new CreateBananaViewModel()
    {
       Type = bananaType
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and leave your POST action as it is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateBananaViewModel model) {}
```

Comment: You're 100% right and I was completely over-complicating the situation and forgetting some of the basics of MVC. I've now set my Clone action to return the Create View with the model, instead of redirecting to the Create method and trying to send the model. Sorry for the dumb question.